# How to Refresh the Google WebApp on every update?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm getting the data from Google sheets and displaying it on Google WebApp front end. But The problem is, the Google WebApp front end don't update itself unless the window is refreshed.

Is there a way to refresh itself when it detects a data change in Google sheets or refreshes itself every 15 minutes.

***index.html***

```
<script>
function onSuccess(UpdatedData) {
var div = document.getElementById('output');

div.innerHTML = '<div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap fw-normal" style="width: 6rem; ">Last Updated:</div> <span class="font-weight-normal text-muted fs-6">'+ UpdatedData + '</span>';
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getdata();
</script>

<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How about wrapping your funtion inside a `setInterval(()=>{},9e5)`, this would call the function every 15 minutes.[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). Don't thinks there is a google-apps-script built in for achieve this.

Comment: @Emel I'm not a coder, I have no idea how to wrap the code 'setInterval(()=>{},9e5)' inside a function. my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function to execute every X seconds, you can use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) method.

For example, in your script:

```html
<script>
   function onSuccess(UpdatedData) {
     var div = document.getElementById('output');
   
     div.innerHTML = '<div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap fw-normal" style="width: 6rem; ">Last       Updated:</div> <span class="font-weight-normal text-muted fs-6">'+ UpdatedData + '</span>';
     }
     setInterval(()=>{
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getdata()
     },1e4)
     
</script>
<body>
   <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

This will make the function inside the `setInerval` run every 10 second (10 seconds == `1e4`, the time should be in milliseconds). So for refreshing it every 15 minuts you should use `9e5`

Comment: That worked very well,  :) having 10 seconds interval will it reduce the quota of GAS or will it have any other issues?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad yo hear it. No, but you should adjust it to the requirments of your project.